# 'Win $100 IN art' vs 'Win $100 OF art'

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'm writing some ad copy and we have a healthy disagreement about which of the following we should use:

1. Win $100 *in* art
2. Win $100 *of* art

Which one is correct, clearer, or more established?

The intended meaning is that the recipient would win a $100 gift card with which they can purchase art.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145702/discussion-on-question-by-fife-win-100-in-art-vs-win-100-of-art); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use “of”.

In my experience, *in* is used for more “abstract” concepts whereas of is for quantifying tangible things.

For example:

> $25 in US Dollars is about $1350 in Dominican Pesos.

Or

> With excessive coupon usage, he managed to get $250 in savings at the grocery store this month.

Or

> The plaintiffs are seeking $25000 in reparations from the case.
> They stole $5000 of gold bars from the bank.

Or

> He spent his savings on about $500 of apple juice.

However, both work and using *in* instead of *of* wouldn’t make the meaning unclear in my opinion. *In* might work better than *of* if you change “art” to something like “art credit” (although art credit sounds weird so you ought to use something that is similar in meaning.)

Comment: Please cite your sources in accordance with our rules; "in my experience" is not sufficient.

Comment: I've heard things like "$100 in baseball cards". What's meant is "$100 worth of baseball cards".

Comment: One of the reasons for using 'in' is that a voucher can be augmented with money. If the winner wanted to buy a $180 paining, for instance, they could pay for it with the voucher and $80 dollars in cash. Once purchased the painting could not be separated into the portion that was bought with cash and the portion that was bought with the voucher. This, to me, would mean that the winner had not bought "$100 worth _of_ art". They would have bought $180 worth of art but they would have won $100 worth _in_ art which had been used as part payment.

Comment: I think the abstract vs concrete, or medium vs product, is the key difference. "In" is commonly used with currency and financial instruments, e.g. "$100 in travellers' checks". If talking about goods, "of" is definitely more common - "$2 of cheese" or "$10 of steak". Art is maybe a bit more abstract than beefsteak, but in this context it means "pictures or sculptures", which are goods.

Answer (score 1):

> **Win $100 in art.**

Compare "He paid me $1,000 but he paid me in one dollar notes!" or "She left in anger"

**In** = in the form/state of

OED:

> **19. Expressing physical, mental, or moral condition or state.**
>
> a. Followed by an abstract noun; e.g. in comfort, in doubt, in health, in hope, in pain, in sickness, in solitude, in sorrow, etc.
>
> 1928   N.Y. Times 4 May 24/3   It was just helping somebody in trouble.

> **Win $100 of art**

**Of** = contextually associated with.

Win $100 of art = Win $100 associated contextually with art.

This is unclear in its meaning and is made worse by **Art** is uncountable in this context and therefore a concept rather than a physical quantity.

OED **art** (n.)

> **8a The expression or application of creative skill and imagination, typically in a visual form such as painting, drawing, or sculpture, producing works to be appreciated primarily for their beauty or emotional power.**

To make sense you would need the **plural, countable** form "artworks" or "works of art".